# google analytics embed api with turbolinks in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics-api, turbolinks-5

I am trying to implement the google analytics embed api using javascript code provided by google to my rails app and taking help from this link -> https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/. Now I dont know how to run these scripts on every page change because these javascripts listens to the page load event and rails uses turbolinks that actually doesn't loads the page it swaps only body and title. Now the problem is that javascript doesn't respond as it does not know that page has been changed. Please help me out.

```
<script>
(function (w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
    g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {}); g.analytics = { q: [], ready: function (f) { this.q.push(f); } };
    js = d.createElement(s); fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs); js.onload = function () { g.load('analytics'); };
}(window, document, 'script'));
</script>
<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>
<script>

gapi.analytics.ready(function () {

    /**
     * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
     * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
     * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
     */
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
        clientid: '7xxxxxxxxxx-mtgoounogp8pu2brjsi1mfpbrohtcppd.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });


    /**
     * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
     * element with the id "view-selector-container".
     */
    var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
        container: 'view-selector-container'
    });

    // Render the view selector to the page.
    viewSelector.execute();


    /**
     * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
     * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
     * with the id "chart-container".
     */
    var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        reportType: 'ga',
        query: {
            metrics: 'ga:sessions',
            dimensions: 'ga:date',
            'start-date': '30daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday'
        },
        chart: {
            container: 'chart-container',
            type: 'LINE',
            options: {
                width: '100%'
            }
        }
    });


    /**
     * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
     */
    viewSelector.on('change', function (ids) {
        dataChart.set({ query: { ids: ids } }).execute();
    });

});
</script>
```

for the very first time my code is running properly but if i switch to another link or come back to the same page after visiting another page via turbolinks the javascript doesn't run.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: you are technically using the embedded API not the reporting API.  The embedded API is a JavaScript implementation of the reporting API.    You might want to reword your question a little to make it clear what you are doing.

Comment: Put that code in the `<head>`

Comment: removed the turbolinks from the view and now it works... thanks all for your attention :)